# Writing credit card information to a new card

Tags: credit-card, magnetic-stripe-card

I'm learning about how credit cards work, and I want to clone my credit card's magnetic stripe to a new regular card (not a credit card, but for example a "club card")

I know that magnetic cards have something called **tracks**. I saw on google that credit cards have 3 tracks. Must my new card also have 3 tracks, or are "tracks" virtual and you can change the number of tracks a card has?

I've also seen [online](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2012/ph240/landreman1/docs/MAGSTRIPE.pdf) that some tracks are **read-only**, does that mean I won't be able to write to those tracks? Sources like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNtFIji81f4) video write to this track, so this seems odd...

Comment: Only a comment, by I really doubt that what you want to do is legal. In many contracts, the bank is still the real owner of the card and you are only allowed to use it. So physicaly extracting the card is likely to be illegal in most countries...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Ok so I've read the "terms and conditions" of my credit card company. I'm not allowed to make any change to the card itself, so I'm not allowed to take out the emv chip.  It doesn't say I'm not allowed to clone the magnetic stripe, so I think I'm safe on that part :)

Comment: How does gluing a chip on another card make it "fully functional"? Have you confirmed that any random card is writable? I'm not sure this is a security question. And it looks like you need to do some further research on the first principles before you get too far down the road in your project planning. So, confirm your assumptions and questions and then ask a single question. Also, if you find out that part of your question doesn't work, remove that part instead of adding an addendum to negate it.